# Servlet Mapping URL pattern

Tags: servlets

```
webapps
|
|----helloworld
     |
     |----WEB-INF
          |
          |-----classes-HelloWorldServlet.class
          |-----lib----servlet-api.jar
          |-----web.xml
```

The above is my directory structure. Now in web.xml i don't know what to give in url-pattern for servlet mapping. What should i give there? Which is the url pattern?

Comment: The directory structure is irrelevant to the `url-pattern`. It's whatever *you* want it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism for mapping servlets is not relevant to the directory structure, as skaffman noted.

Basically, you have two things in web.xml (regarding servlets):

- the `<servlet>` tag, which defines the alias for the servlet, and its fully-qualified name (for example `com.foo.pkg.YourServlet`)
- the `<servlet-mapping>` which specifies a `url-pattern` for a given alias (taken from the `<servlet>` definitions).

As the name suggest, the url-pattern denotes what URL portion should make the servlet be called. So if you map a given servlet to the url-pattern `/myfirstserlet`, it will be accessible when the user opens `http://localhost:8080/helloword/myfirstservlet`, where the first part is the host name and the port, followed by the context name (the name of your webapp), and then the url-pattern

Note: you are currently using the default package (i.e. no package) for your servlet. This is discouraged, so give it some package name. (and put it in `WEB-INF/classes/com/foo/pkg/`). This is done via specifying `package com.foo.pkg;`

Comment: If i want something like http://localhost:8080/helloword/war/myfirstservlet, how can it be achieved?

Comment: map it to `/war/myfirstservlet`, and place it in webapps/helloworld

Comment: thank you, but i don't think i understand, i tried it, please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5650136/543544