# GWT Tomcat problem to RPC call

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, rpc

GWT RPC call don't seems to work when i deploy my war file to TOMCAT (tomcat/webapps/ROOT/war).

It gives me an error:

> The requested resource
>   (/war/myproject/call) is not
>   available.

***If i change the directory structure and then deploy directly war contents (not war directory itself), like (tomcat/webapps/ROOT/project.html, project.css, project, etc...) then it works.***

Can someone please explain me whats going on?

I think there might a problem at:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>callServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.myproject.server.dao.Call</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>callServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/myproject/call</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that a single Tomcat server can have multiple applications deployed, each in its so-called *context*. The applications are deployed in the `webapps` folder and each folder is mapped to one *context*, while the `ROOT` folder is the default (no-context).

To access an application on Tomcat, you specify the *context* after the URL. For example if you had an application (context) `Test` in `webapps/Test` folder, you would access it like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/Test
```

But applications in the `ROOT` folder have no context and are accessed by simply going to `localhost:8080`. And this is your case. Tomcat is looking for you application directly in the `ROOT` folder but you have your app in the `ROOT/war` folder. In other words, the RPC call expects the `myproject` folder to be under the `ROOT` folder and not under the `ROOT/war` folder. That's why it's not working.

If you still wanted to have your `war` folder within the `ROOT` folder, you would have to change the `url-pattern` to `/war/myProject/call`.

Comment: Very nice answer, please show me how to change @RemoteServiceRelative path to work.

Comment: I suppose that now your annotation looks like this: @RemoteServiceRelativePath("myProject"). I think that you would need to change it to @RemoteServiceRelativePath("war/myProject") so it conforms with the `url-pattern`. But I, personally, would place the app either directly into the `ROOT` folder, or into a different context, e.g. `webapps/MyProject`.

Comment: Well the case is that i deploy my project to cloudbees. I select a simple .war file to upload. It automatically deploys http://localhost:8080/war/Myproject.html , can't access it with http://localhost:8080/Myproject.html

Comment: I i change it to @RemoteServiceRelativePath("war/myProject"), it gives me 404 not found requested URI

Comment: Oh, then try changing the url-pattern to `<url-pattern>/war/myproject/call</url-pattern>` and the annotation to `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("myProject")`

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the paths. The annotation value should remain "call". I suppose you had this that way before, right?

Comment: And it still doesn't work when the url-pattern is set to `/war/myproject/call` and the annotation's value is "call" ?

Comment: Could you please update your question with your current web.xml and your declaration of the class with the @RemoteServiceRelativePath annotation?

Comment: here's my: @RemoteServiceRelativePath("../rpc-endpoint-configuration"). Servlet is listening on ${context}/rpc-endpoint-configuration. Since the service is defined under AdminUI module, I need a step up. I could have defined servlet mapping to /AdminUI too, either way works. The point is: the name of your war is your context: MyApp.war becomes /MyApp/ context. This context is the root of your URIs, i.e. servlet mappings and RPC config shall NOT include it, but should start right under it.

Answer (score 1):

Well i found the solution, it had to do  with Tomcat's way of operation.

1. Open your project war directory
2. Select all the files (html/jsp , images, WEB-INF etc...)
3. Compress all the files into a single project.zip archieve
4. Rename the project.zip into project.war
5. Copy project.war into Tomcat/webapps/
6. Restart Tomcat server
7. You will now notice inside webapps directory that project.war has been decompressed into a project directory, if you open it you will find all the .war contents(html/jsp, images, WEB-INF, etc...)
8. Access it from here http://localhost/project or http://localhost/project/index.html or index.jsp.

*The error was: I was compressing only the war directory (not it's inside contents) into project.war.*

Comment: And @RemoteServiceRelativePath("call"), <url-pattern>/call</url-pattern>

Comment: I didn't change anything i left default urls. GWT has design it's folder structure so that it is compatible for external server deployment

Comment: Glad you got it solved. I recommend using Maven for building your application and generating the WAR package. It's really worth learning at least the basics and it will save you a lot of trouble. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

look like, servlet is not initializing for you war try to change SERVLET tag as
i.e. add tag

```
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

this tag ensures that servlet should be loaded

```
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>callServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.myproject.server.dao.Call</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

hopefully this will work

Comment: did you restarts server after deployment, try it, it may work

Comment: @Imran I did, i think it was a minor error. I use GWT which compiles JAVA to Javascript, i didn't re-compiled ...

Comment: Try 1 more thing dont put war in ROOT folder put it directly under webapp i.e. $tomcat\webapps\yourproject.war